# Titanium and PHP - Blank Screen

Tags: php, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to build a desktop PHP app.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/php">
$heading=$document->getElementById("title");
$heading->innerHTML="Now i see you!";

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I launch the desktop app it comes up blank. The basic hello world works fine if I don't try to use php. Am I using the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Titanium, but there is no element with an id of 'title' to set the value of.
Does the following work?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/php">
$heading=$document->getElementById("title");
$heading->innerHTML="Now i see you!";

</script>
<h1 id="title"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```